# how in OBIEE convert rows into columns in analytics

Tags: obiee

For a certain program I have some type-keywords values like this:

```
Program     Type    Keyword
PIM         Kind    Additional 
PIM         Period  Education
PIM         Phase   Specialized
PIM         Skills  Professional
```

The type is a fixed value, but the keyword depends of the Program and type. I want to transpose this result in analytics by making 4 columns with the type. The result has to look like this:

```
Program Kind        period      phase           skills
PIM     Additional  Education   Specialized     Professional
```

I have tried by editing the column formula and putting this formula:

```
CASE WHEN "Type"='Partial period' THEN "Keyword" END
```

and so on for each different type. But it doesn't give me the result I want. all the new columns are empty.

I also tried with a pivot table, but the keyword isn't a measure, so I don't think this will work. 
can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

This simply doesn't make sense in an analytical way. You have no fact, nothing you measure. So no chance of using FILTER...USING... for example.

Don't forget you're not in Excel or a drawing tool. You're in an analytics tool which tries to make sense out of data and not "show data in a weird way".

You have to model things nicely either in the data source itself or be clever in the construction of your RPD.

It's doable in the RPD but it will be quite static and if the list of values changes you will have to adapt it.

tl;dr - garbage data, garbage result